Calculating correction term for Non-constant Temperature situations in Relation between Height and Air pressure
Background
We initially have $$p(h+\Delta)-p(h)=-g\rho(\xi)\Delta$$ as of the definition of pressure, where $p(h)$ is the pressure at height $h$, $\rho(h)$ is the air density at height $h$.
By taking limits of it, we get:
$$p'(h)=-g\rho(h)\tag{1}$$
By Clapeyron's Law we have:
$$\frac{pV}{T}=R$$
Where $R$ is the universal gas constant. By setting $M$ as the molar mass of air, $V$ as the molar volume of air. We have from the above that:
$$p=\frac 1V RT=\frac MV\frac RM T=\rho \frac RM T\tag{2}$$
And by setting $\lambda(T)=\frac RM T,$
We have $$p=\lambda(T)\rho\tag{3}$$
And by combining (1) and (3) we get:
$$p'(h)=-\frac g\lambda p(h)\tag{4}$$
By operating on the ODE in (4) we finally get
$$ p(h)=p(0)e^{-(g/\lambda)h}$$
Now the problem asks us to:
Using the data from the above, obtain a formula for a correction term to take account of the dependence of pressure  on the temperature of the air column, if  the temperature is subject to variation, within the range of $\pm 40 ^{\circ}
C$.
I noticed that the premise was taken as the temperature is constant, and now we are asked to prove the correction term for the case when it is non constant. But I don't really understand why and how it should be constant in accordance with the equation, and what we do to in turn solve the problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Correction Term for Non-constant Temperature Situations in the Relation between Height and Air Pressure
Given the relationship between pressure and height:
$$ p(h+\Delta) - p(h) = -g \rho(\xi) \Delta $$
Taking the limit as (\Delta \to 0), we get:
$$ \frac{dp(h)}{dh} = -g \rho(h) \tag{1} $$
Using the ideal gas law, we have:
$$ pV = RT $$
where (R) is the universal gas constant. Expressing this in terms of density (\rho) and molar mass (M):
$$ p = \frac{\rho R T}{M} $$
Thus, combining this with equation (1), we get:
$$ \frac{dp}{dh} = -\frac{gM}{RT} p $$
Non-constant Temperature
If the temperature (T) varies with height (h), we denote it as (T(h)). Therefore, the differential equation becomes:
$$ \frac{dp(h)}{dh} = -\frac{gM}{R T(h)} p(h) $$
To solve this differential equation, we can rewrite it as:
$$ \frac{1}{p(h)} \frac{dp(h)}{dh} = -\frac{gM}{R T(h)} $$
Integrating both sides:
$$ \int \frac{1}{p(h)} \, dp(h) = -\frac{gM}{R} \int \frac{1}{T(h)} \, dh $$
$$ \ln p(h) = -\frac{gM}{R} \int_0^h \frac{1}{T(\xi)} \, d\xi + C $$
where (C) is the integration constant.
$$ p(h) = p(0) \exp \left( -\frac{gM}{R} \int_0^h \frac{1}{T(\xi)} \, d\xi \right) $$
Correction Term for Temperature Variation
To find a correction term due to temperature variation, consider (T(h) = T_0 + \Delta T(h)), where (T_0) is a reference temperature and (\Delta T(h)) is the deviation. Assuming (\Delta T(h)) is small compared to (T_0), we can approximate:
$$ \frac{1}{T(h)} \approx \frac{1}{T_0} - \frac{\Delta T(h)}{T_0^2} $$
Using this approximation:
$$ \int_0^h \frac{1}{T(\xi)} \, d\xi \approx \int_0^h \left( \frac{1}{T_0} - \frac{\Delta T(\xi)}{T_0^2} \right) d\xi $$
$$ = \frac{h}{T_0} - \frac{1}{T_0^2} \int_0^h \Delta T(\xi) \, d\xi $$
Corrected Pressure Formula
Substituting this into the exponent:
$$ p(h) = p(0) \exp \left( -\frac{gM}{R} \left( \frac{h}{T_0} - \frac{1}{T_0^2} \int_0^h \Delta T(\xi) \, d\xi \right) \right) $$
$$ = p(0) \exp \left( -\frac{gM h}{R T_0} \right) \exp \left( \frac{gM}{R T_0^2} \int_0^h \Delta T(\xi) \, d\xi \right) $$
Conclusion
The correction term due to temperature variation is:
$$ \exp \left( \frac{gM}{R T_0^2} \int_0^h \Delta T(\xi) \, d\xi \right) $$
Thus, the corrected formula for pressure as a function of height, taking into account the temperature variation, is:
$$ p(h) = p(0) \exp \left( -\frac{gM h}{R T_0} \right) \exp \left( \frac{gM}{R T_0^2} \int_0^h \Delta T(\xi) \, d\xi \right) $$
This correction term allows for the pressure calculation to adapt to variations in temperature within the specified range.

$$ \int \frac{1}{p(h)} , dp(h) = -\frac{gM}{R} \int \frac{1}{T(h)} , dh $$
$$ \ln p(h) = -\frac{gM}{R} \int_0^h \frac{1}{T(\xi)} , d\xi + C $$
I don't really understand this line, that how does the integral goes from indefinite to definite.

@YinuoAn the integral goes from indefinite to definite by choosing two integration bowndries. I chose the origin of the system to be at h=0.
